# mysql server suddenly crash

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

so my Mysql server has been working just fine, but suddenly out of the blue now whenever I try to load it up it returns this error:

```
110827 18:42:06 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
110827 18:42:06  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 42897533
110827 18:42:06 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
110827 18:42:06 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
110827 18:42:06 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
110827 18:42:06 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
110827 18:42:06 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.36-community-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
110827 18:42:15  InnoDB: Operating system error number 995 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File name .\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'Windows aio'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

anyone knows why this is happening and how to fix it? I'm using wampserver 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Following the links provided in your question, I get to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681388.aspx, which describes Error 995 as:

> The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

That sounds vaguely like MySQL actually *asked* to abort the operation, or else a thread died unceremoniously.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an old MySQL bug report on [error 995](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3139) in which a couple things are suggested:

- Tune innodb_file_io_threads: "Number of file i/o threads in InnoDB. Normally, this should be 4, but on Windows disk i/o may benefit from a larger number. Numeric my.cnf parameter format. "
- Depending on what version of MySQL you're running, a fix was put into 5.1.42. See if you can upgrade to that version if you're not running it.
- Potentially an OS bug/failure. Try running the DB on a different machine.